# Template, visibility, static attribute and shared libraries

Tags: c++, templates, static, shared-libraries, visibility

The question is about the static attribut of an instanciation of a template class when used by a shared library and by an executable.

The test contains a few classes: PoolObject (the template class), Session (instanciation of the class template). Session is defined in a shared library, and used in main program.

PoolObject is a template class that redefines operators new and delete. It contains a static attribut, which address is printed in both operators.

Section is an instanciation of PoolObject. libSection is a dynamic library, that defines methods of Section.

The main program simply creates a new section and deletes it.

Messages in operators new and delete show that the static attribut is not the same. However, if both constructor and destructor of Session are defined into the header instead of in .cpp, the address of the static attribut is the same.

May anyone explain this behavior?

Some observations:

- changing the visibity of Session (with _Pragma("GCC visibility push(default)")), the address of the static attribut is the same.
- if parameter of the template is changed from Session to int, the address of the static attribut is the same.
- works with gcc.

Code:

Session.hpp:

```
#ifndef _SECTION_HPP_
#define _SECTION_HPP_

#include "Pool.hpp"

//_Pragma("GCC visibility push(default)")
struct Section : PoolObject<Section>
{
  Section();
  virtual ~Section();

  void dummy();
};
//_Pragma("GCC visibility pop")

#endif
```

Session.cpp

```
#include "Section.hpp"

Section::Section()
{
}

Section::~Section()
{
}

void
Section::dummy()
{
  printf("Section::dummy\n");
}
```

PoolObject.hpp

```
#ifndef _POOL_HPP_
#define _POOL_HPP_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

_Pragma("GCC visibility push(default)")
template<typename T>
class PoolObject
{
   private:
      static int *m_pool;

   public:
      void *operator new(size_t size) {
         printf("[PoolObject] : new, pool:%p, sizeof(T):%zd\n", &m_pool, sizeof(T));
         return malloc(size); 
      }
      void operator delete(void *pointer) {
         printf("[PoolObject] : del, pool:%p\n", &m_pool);
         free(pointer); 
      }
};

template<typename T> int* PoolObject<T>::m_pool = 0;

_Pragma("GCC visibility pop")

#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Section.hpp"

int main() {
  Section *section = new Section();
  delete section;
  return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
defaut: clean run

CC := clang++-11
#CC := g++

FLAGS_COMMON := -fPIC -std=c++17 -W -Wall -O3 # -ffunction-sections

FLAGS_SECTION := $(FLAGS_COMMON) -fvisibility=default
FLAGS_MAIN := $(FLAGS_COMMON) -fvisibility=hidden

libsection: Section.cpp
    $(CC) -shared Section.cpp -o libSection.so -I . $(FLAGS_SECTION)

test: libsection
    $(CC) main.cpp -I . -lSection -L. -o test $(FLAGS_MAIN)

all: test

run: test
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./test

clean:
    rm -f *.so test
```

Output:
[PoolObject] : new, pool:0x404060, sizeof(T):8
[PoolObject] : del, pool:0x7fedbf1a7040

Comment: Cannot reproduce with gcc.

Comment: Just one question, who/what will delete your m_pool?

Comment: @PepijnKramer, In the example, m_pool it is not created or deleted, this is because the test has been extremely simplified to show just the issue. In the real project, m_pool is a big block of memory used by new/delete. It is never deleted.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. I can reproduce it with gcc, with this version "g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0". However, the behavior is slightly different as defining the destructor in header file is enough to remove the issue.